# TSQL - Get sum or substract from two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to sum/substract 'salevalue' from the two tables in my procedure. Sale 1 has receipts, 2nd is with returns. But I am lost in ideas.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM @possale1

    SELECT *
    FROM @possale2

    SELECT sum(salevalue) AS S1
    FROM @possale1

    SELECT sum(salevalue)*-1 AS S2
    FROM @possale2

    select sum(sum(a.salevalue)-sum(b.salevalue)) 
    from @possale1 a 
    inner join @possale2 b on a.receiptdate=b.receiptdate
```

Comment: "I am lost in ideas" is not really a question that can be answered. Please try to clarify your reasoning. Maybe, by writing down your thoughts, you may arrive at the correct answer yourself.

Comment: My bad I didn't make it more precise.

I have a stored procedure which inserts receipts and returns from Oracle via OpenQuery into to two separate tables.

Now I want to have a substract from those to tables (receipts - returns = balance).

Arvo anwsered my question and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without aggregation next should do:

```
select ((SELECT sum(salevalue) FROM @possale1) - (SELECT sum(salevalue) FROM @possale2)) as balance
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that gave me a substract I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying for this ?

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(a.salevalue,0) - ISNULL(b.salevalue,0))
FROM @possale1 a FULL OUTER JOIN @possale2 b on a.receiptdate=b.receiptdate
```

Comment: That only works if both tables have exactly 1 row for each date.